# Shrinking Linux Partition without Installs

Tags: linux, bash, partitioning, terminal

If I have a linux partition that I'd like to change the size of (either expand or shrink), how would I go about doing that without using a Live CD/USB stick or gparted (or something similar like lextend)?  I'm particularly interested in how to change the size of a partition of a filesystem that I'm working from (i.e. booting in Mint and changing the partition size of the Mint partition).

I'd prefer to do all of the work from the terminal.

Comment: Have you tried gparted?

Comment: +1 for gparted, but if you must use the terminal here's a good [Q&A on using parted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24027/how-can-i-resize-an-ext-root-partition-at-runtime)

Comment: @SDSolar I'm aware of gparted and I'd like to not use it

Comment: @pcdev oh awesome. Thanks. That's exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for.

Comment: See my answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/630411/why-is-it-not-possible-to-resize-move-mounted-non-logical-partitions-at-runtim) and to [this one.](https://superuser.com/questions/660309/live-resize-of-a-gpt-partition-on-linux)